# I can't get <pmlcore:Sensor with XElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xelement

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application with .NET Framework 4.5.1 that returns XML generated from database data.

I want to obtain this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pmlcore:Sensor [ Ommitted for brevety ] ">
```

But I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sensor [ Ommitted for brevety ]  xmlns="pmlcore">
```

Reading all the answers found in Stackoverflow, I changed my code to use `XNamespace`:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XDeclaration dec = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);

XNamespace pmlcore = "pmlcore";
XNamespace pmluid = "pmluid";

root = new XElement(pmlcore + "Sensor"
    , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "pmluid", 
        "urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1")
    , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", ns)
    , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "pmlcore", 
        "urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1")
    , new XAttribute(ns + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation",
                     "urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1 ./PML/SchemaFiles/Interchange/PMLCore.xsd")
```

How can I obtain `<pmlcore:Sensor` this?

If I use this code:

```
root = new XElement("pmlcore:Sensor"
```

I get this error:

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a
>   name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the wrong namespace... you're trying to use the *alias* for it, instead of the namespace URI. Here's a concrete example that works:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XNamespace pmlcore = "urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1";
        XNamespace pmluid = "urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1";

        var root = new XElement(pmlcore + "Sensor",
             new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "pmluid", pmluid.NamespaceName),
             new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "pmlcore", pmlcore.NamespaceName));
        Console.WriteLine(root);
    }
}
```

Output (reformatted):

```
<pmlcore:Sensor
  xmlns:pmluid="urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1"
  xmlns:pmlcore="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1" />
```